# can't install or upgrade packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

Every time i try to update or install package, i get the following error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

i've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get check  
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

What went wrong and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If you would like to read more about difference between upgrade vs dist-upgrade:

```
man apt-get |grep -A 4 dist-upgrade
```